# Is there any difference between this and self when assigning curried functions inside an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, this, self

Suppose I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header><h1>test</h1></header>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction2Wrapper(arg1) {
            return function() {
                console.log("state of arg1 in a curried function is: " + arg1);
            }
        }

        function MyObject() {
            var internalState1 = "a";

            function myFunction1() {
                console.log("state of internalState1: " + internalState1);
            }
            myFunction1();

            this.myFunction2 = myFunction2Wrapper(internalState1);
            //self.myFunction2 = myFunction2Wrapper(internalState1);

            myFunction2();

            //console.log(myFunction2);

            console.log("done!");

        };

        MyObject();



    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note in particular the lines:

```
this.myFunction2 = myFunction2Wrapper(internalState1);
//self.myFunction2 = myFunction2Wrapper(internalState1);
```

My question is: **Is there any difference between `this` and `self` when assigning curried functions inside an object in JavaScript?**

Comment: Use native ES5 `.bind()` method to set the context. See http://kishorelive.com/2012/02/06/currying-in-javascript-using-bind/

Comment: If you uncommented the `self.myFunction2 = ...` line you'd get an error because `self` is not defined. But `self` versus `this` is not relevant here because `MyObject()` is the only function that refers to `this`. Whether any currying is taking place is not related. Also, because you called `MyObject()` without `new`, its value of `this` will be `window`, which means `this.myFunction2 = ...` creates a new global function - which is why you can then call `myFunction2()` the way you do.

Comment: `self` is actually defined and refers to `window.self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `self` implicit context/parameter. `self` used inside any function actually refers to `window.self` which is equal to `window`, not to `this`.

Note: On global scope functions, `this` refers to `window`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the code that you put of example the idea of using `this` and `self` is not clear, `self` usually is used for when the cotext changed. For example:

```
function MyClass(){
   this.element = 'some';
   this.anotherElement = []; 
}

//now references of the properties of MyClass be with self
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function(e){
    self = this;
    self.element.length;
    self.anotherElement.push('4');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS due to the loose and playful state of `this`, the `that` or `self` phrases are mostly preferred among developers to harbor the `this` value at certain stages of their algorithm. However using `self` should be avoided since unlike `that`, `self` is a keyword in JS which represents the global context of the each web worker domain. Since the global scope in the worker context is called [self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) and accessed as `self` using self keyword for other purposes should be discouraged.